# Needs to disable the cmd pop up when i call vbs through c#

Tags: c#

I used the following lines in the vbs script, which called .vbs from the C#.

```
objShell.Run("net stop msdtc"),1,True
objShell.Run("net start msdtc"),1,True
```

In c$, the follwoing code used for calling .vbs with administrative privillage. Even though i set the WindowStyle to hidden the cmd pop up opens at runtime. I dont want to open pop up. please help me

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"cscript.exe DTCSECURITY.vbs");
ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;                
ProcessInfo.UserName = @"administrator";
ProcessInfo.Password = StringToSecureString("password12$");
ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `CreateNoWindow = true;` (see the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx)).

`ProcessWindowStyle` dictates the [state of the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) (in terms of maximised, minimised, visible etc.) once it has been created.

Comment: i tried with the below code,

 ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;     

 but no hope, actually it wasn't solved my problem

Comment: See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: then can i change the value at run to hide the window ? what is the cmd parameter value for hidden ?

Comment: solution objShell.Run("net stop msdtc"),0,True solved to hide the popup

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

> CreateNoWindow:
>
> Allows you to run a command line program silently. It
>    does not flash a console window.

Comment: Even after given ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; i face the same issue.. not resolved

Comment: Bear in mind that `Run` calls could activate a window. Notably, `1` means "Activate and display the window".

Comment: Are those two lines your complete .vbs script or are you running more code in the script?

Comment: You could try to start the command from the the C# code instead of the script. ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","net stop msdtc"); I don't know if it will help but it's worth testing.

Comment: hi grant thomas thanks for your solution, if i gave the parameter 0, the cmd window runs in the minimized mode.
objShell.Run("net stop msdtc"),0,True
objShell.Run("net start msdtc"),0,True

But one more porblem, when i was running process with administratative credential a empty cmd pop shows. how to hide this ? The administrative code as below

ProcessInfo.UserName = @"administrator";
ProcessInfo.Password = StringToSecureString("password12$"